# Cambiar opción seleccionada ComboBox por JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap

estaba realizando un formulario para insertar y modificar usuarios. El problema me ha llegado cuando he querido modificar un usuario y, al intentar mandarle la opción que quiero, no me la coge.
Los datos los recibo en forma de un array ofrecidos por una consulta mediante **ajax**. Y utilizo **bootstrap** para poder coger los datos de la tabla.

A la hora de introducirlos establezco que el campo que se va a ver es un texto pero realmente voy a trabajar con números (siendo cada número un dato que me devuelve ajax).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi combo box (y los valores corresponden al 13,14,15). Y adjunto el código del combo box:

```
<select id="tipo" name="tipo" class="selectpicker" data-title="Selecciona el tipo de usuario" data-style="btn-default btn-block" data-menu-style="dropdown-blue"></select>
```

Para poder recuperar los datos lo que hago es darle a un botón que tiene la clase *'.fa-edit'* y con ello puedo coger los datos de esa tabla.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.fa-edit, .div-edit', function () {
    en_modificacion = addEditStyles($(this));
    var data = getDataTable($(this));

    cod_usuario = data.COD;
    if (undefined != data)
    {
        $('#usuario').val(data.USUARIO);
        $('#password').val(data.CONTRASEÑA);
        $('#nombre').val(data.NOMBRE);
        $('#apellido1').val(data.APELLIDO1);
        $('#apellido2').val(data.APELLIDO2);
        $('#chPublicidad').prop("checked", data.NO_PUBLI);
        $('#chNotificaciones').prop("checked", data.NO_NOTIFICACIONES);
        $('#fecha-nacimiento').val(data.FECHA_NACIMIENTO);
        $('#telefono_fijo').val(data.FIJO);
        $('#telefono_movil').val(data.MOVIL);
        document.getElementById('tipo').value = 15;
        //$('#tipo').data(data.TIPO_USUARIO); // Esto sería para obtener el texto del tipo del código
        //$('#tipo').data(data.COD_USU); // Esto sería para obtener el número del tipo del código
    }

});
```

Con el resto de inputs no tengo ningún problema.
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola Sergio, esta pregunta es interesante y se ajusta bien a la temática del sitio. Además de lo que has intentado, deberías incluir algo más de código (¿cómo se genera el select?¿qué biblioteca usas para generarlo?) para que podamos reproducir el problema y ayudarte a resolverlo. Tal y como está ahora, al no tener el código del combobox, no podemos saber qué falla con lo que has intentado. Lee cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Si sabes el indice puedes usar `document.getElementById('tipo').selectedIndex = i` donde i es el indice

Comment: He asignado más información del problema para ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si `$('#tipo').val(15)` o `$('#tipo').val("15")` no te funciona directamente una opción es probar

`$("#tipo").val(15).change()`

para recuperar el foco después del cambio.

Otra opción es, si hay una opción previamente seleccionada, deseleccionarla antes de seleccionar la nueva.

```
$("#tipo").removeAttr("selected");
```

Comment: Perfecto, me funcionó. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Un placer Sergio :)